# Show Twitter Feed on my website

Tags: php, twitter

Up until a few weeks ago the below code worked great to grab my last three tweets and display them on my website. now it's not working. I've looked through Twitter's messages boards to see if something changed to no avail.

Does anyone know how to effectively display your latest tweets on a website using php?

my original code is here. Like I said, this worked up until a few weeks ago:

```
$twitterUsername = "myUsername";
$amountToShow = 3;
$twitterRssFeedUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name='.$twitterUsername.'&count='.$amountToShow;

$twitterPosts = false;
$xml = @simplexml_load_file($twitterRssFeedUrl);
if(is_object($xml)){
    foreach($xml->channel->item as $twit){
    if(is_array($twitterPosts) && count($twitterPosts)==$amountToShow){
    break;
}
$d['title'] = stripslashes(htmlentities($twit->title,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
$description = stripslashes(htmlentities($twit->description,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
if(strtolower(substr($description,0,strlen($twitterUsername))) == strtolower($twitterUsername)){
    $description = substr($description,strlen($twitterUsername)+1);
}
$d['description'] = $description;
$d['pubdate'] = strtotime($twit->pubDate);
$d['guid'] = stripslashes(htmlentities($twit->guid,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
$d['link'] = stripslashes(htmlentities($twit->link,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
$twitterPosts[]=$d;
}
}else{

die('Can`t fetch the feed you requested');
}
```

and then it turns up in the html like so:

```
 <dl class="twitter">
      <dt>Twitter Feed</dt>
<?php
if(is_array($twitterPosts)){
echo '';
foreach($twitterPosts as $post){ 
$data = hyperlinks($post['description']);
$data = twitter_users($data);
 echo '<dd>'.$data.'. ';
 echo '<a href="'.$post['link'].'" class="timestamp">Posted '.time2str(date($post['pubdate'])).'</a></dd>';
}
echo '';
}else{
    echo 'No Twitter posts have been made';//Error message
}
?>
     <dd>
```

Comment: So what is not working now?  Have you tried to debug the code to see where it is failing?

Comment: https://github.com/andrewbiggart/latest-tweets-php-o-auth/blob/master/tweets.php

Answer (score 2):

Twitter API 1.0 that you're using has been switched off, as of a few weeks ago.

Read up on the API 1.1 here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api

There are tonnes of PHP libraries for working with the new API, including [mine](https://github.com/timwhitlock/php-twitter-api).

Comment: thanks Tim. I'm not much of a developer. do you have any working examples of this?

Comment: 'working' would require me adding my secret credentials into the code. Take a look in the examples folder for examples without secrets removed.

Comment: We don't want you giving out your secret credentials. I have a consumer secret, authorize token, consumer key, request token, etc. can I just plug those into one of your libraries to make it work?

Comment: If you're using Wordpress, then [yes](http://wordpress.org/plugins/latest-tweets-widget/) Otherwise you'll have to write some code. Take `examples/example-api-call.php` as a starting point.

Comment: If you're not a developer and you're not using Wordpress I suggest using Twitter's official [embedded timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines).

Comment: @Tim thanks for this. Your API seems to be exactly what I was looking for, I was just wondering whether you had any documentation for it.

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.